# JList - select multiple items

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jlist, multi-select

I faced a problem with this `setSelectedValue()` method in `JList` when I wanted to select multiple values in a `JList` automatically, it still selected only one.  Is there a way?

```
 String[] items = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" };
      final JList theList = new JList(items);
      theList.setSelectedValue("Item 1",true);
      theList.setSelectedValue("Item 2",true);
```

This code shows only `Item 2` as selected.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `JList.setSelectedIndices(int[])` after calling `JList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION)`.

### E.G.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
class MultiSelectList {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File f = new File("MultiSelectList.java");
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        final ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line!=null) {
            lines.add(line);
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JList list = new JList(lines.toArray());
                list.setSelectionMode(
                    ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
                int[] select = {19, 20, 22};
                list.setSelectedIndices(select);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(list));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### Screen Shot

[image: Screen shot of code]

Comment: @ Nirav follows this Java Swing tutorial http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html and tons of examples for that on http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/List.htm +1

Answer (score 4):

```
list.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(...);
```

or if the selection isn't consecutive then you need to use multiple

```
list.getSelectionModel().addSelectionInterval(...);
```

Comment: yes, It right but I need to select them on the base of values not on index.do have any idea for that?

Answer (score 3):

As you are using the NetBeans GUI editor, you can customize the `Post-Creation Code` generated for your `JList` as shown below.

[image: post-creation dialog]

Comment: @Nirav: As an exercise, compare @Andrew Thompson's example to the generated code.

Comment: now problem is that every time first item is shown as selected. otherwise it works fine.

Comment: @Nirav: Correct, a call to `setSelectedIndices()`, such as @Andrew Thompson has shown, must also be added.

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class MultiSelectList {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File f = new File("MultiSelectList.java");
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        final ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line!=null) {
            lines.add(line);
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JList list = new JList(lines.toArray());
                list.setSelectionMode(
                    ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
                int[] select = {19, 20, 22};
                list.setSelectedIndices(select);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(list));
            }
        });
    }
}
```