# Overriding JList's mutual exclusivity

Tags: java, swing, jlist

For some reason, even though `JList` is, by default, a multi-select list, when one clicks another option, any choices you previously clicked get erased. Also, for some reason, one would have to hold down Ctrl and click, to make otherSelection

I tried to override this, by making custom `ListModel` that has `selectedIndices` stored to it, and adding `MouseListener` to my `JList` that, when activated, will append `list.getSelectedIndices()` to `listModel.selectedIndices`. However, there is unexpected problem with this approach: when stress-testing my solution (I made damn sure I was working out all of the inevitable programming mistakes before proceeding!), I found out that, for example, I could have the second list option selected, but click on the first, and `list.getSelectedIndices()` would return the index for the second option (and thus, my algorithm would fail).

Is there any way to make it so that every click would actually add (or remove) the index of the clicked list option to `list.getSelectedIndices()`, without my workaround?

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By8fFJhNOgyCRFVmSVd0TWtkVmc/view?usp=sharing) is JAR file for testing (`DEBUG == true` so debug output is visible from command line).

Comment: Okay, the immediate problem I have with this is that it's contradictive to the average user's experience.  Try it in Windows Explorer/Finder for example.  To make multiple selections, you use a combination of <CTRL> or <SHIFT>.  About the only solution I could think of would be to replace the Look and Feel delegate...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JList - select multiple items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234893/jlist-select-multiple-items)

Comment: I use `JCheckBox` as the `ListCellRenderer`

Comment: Totally agree with MadProgrammer's comment. In addition don't forget that for a proper UI the user should be able to use the mouse OR the keyboard. When the arrow keys are used the slection is cleared and the row is selected. If you hold down the shift key, then the selection is extended. If you hold the ctrl key you just move up/or down with no selection change. To add a selection you use Ctrl+Space. Again this is well defined behaviour for MS applications which is why Swing works this way.

Answer (score 1):

> I use JCheckBox as the ListCellRenderer

Then maybe you should be using a single column `JTable` with Boolean values. The state of the checkbox will be toggled every time you click on the cell.